# MinGW, C, макрос получения исходника и строки вызова

Tags: c, mingw, macro

Помнится мне, что в `MinGW` был макрос, который позволял делать такое:

```
printf("%s", MACRO);

// Выведет, например: main.c, строка 17
```

Подскажите, как он называется, никак не могу его найти.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%s, строка %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s, строка %d",__FILE__,__LINE__);
```