# Препроцессор: превратить __LINE__ в строку

Tags: c++, c, макросы, препроцессор

Навеяно [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941327/mingw-c-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Все время от времени пользуются отладочным выводом с предопределенными макросами типа

```
cout << __FILE__ << " line " << __LINE__ << endl;
```

Задумался - как написать макрос `FILELINE`, чтоб эту строчку выше заменить на

```
cout << FILELINE << endl;
```

Ну т.е. чтоб макрос раскрывался в строку, в составе которой было число, в которую раскрывается `__LINE__`. Как ни кручусь - все время или число оказывается не в кавычках, или в кавычках оказывается `"__LINE__"`.

Ну не может быть, чтоб эта задача была неразрешима. Ткните носом, о чем я не подумал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Перевод ответа с английского StackOverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343205/c-concatenating-file-and-line-macros/19343239#19343239)

Вам нужно сделать это в несколько этапов:

```
#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)
#define LOCATION __FILE__ " : " S2(__LINE__)
```

Почему?

***Краткий ответ*:** Вам нужно раскрыть макрос `__LINE__`, прежде чем передавать его в `#x`.

***Развернутый ответ:*** Во-первых, используя оператор `#` в функционально-подобном макросе, он должен сопровождаться параметром макроса, но `__LINE__` не является параметром, поэтому компилятор жалуется, что он является ошибочным оператором.

Во-вторых, `__LINE__` сам по себе является макросом и содержит номер текущей строки, его следует раскрыть до числа перед использованием его с `#`, в противном случае вы получите строку `"__LINE __"` вместо числа.

Макрос `S2 (__LINE__)` расширяет `__LINE__` до номера строки, затем мы передаем номер строки в `#x`.

Answer (score 2):

Таки получилось:

```
#define S(x) #x
#define S_(x) S(x)
#define S__LINE__ S_(__LINE__)
#define FILELINE (__FILE__  " line " S__LINE__)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641427/how-to-make-preprocessor-generate-a-string-for-line-keyword

Comment: Большую S я бы так смело не резервировал. Работает.

Comment: я просто скопировал из примера, понятно, что надо что-то более мудрёное